# Use a selected listbox item to open a new window (Python)

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I just started coding with tkinter and am kind of stuck. 
My goal is to create a first window with a list. The user chooses an item from the list. Depending on what item was chosen, a new window pops up where the user can enter stuff for the rest of the program. 
My idea was to create an  if :
 if whatihaveselected===firstitem:
            new window pops up

I have tried read (a lot) of similar topics but I can't seem to really understand what I am doing wrong.

```
import tkinter 

class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()     

def initialize(self):            
    self.grid()

  self.labelVariable = tkinter.StringVar()
    label = tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                       font=('courier',10,'bold'),anchor="w",fg="red",bg="white")
    label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
    self.labelVariable.set(u"Modélisation de populations atteintes d'un virus")

    v=tkinter.Listbox(self)
    v.insert("end","Modèle SIR")
    v.insert("end", "Modèle de Witowski")
    v.insert("end", "Modèle de Munz")
    v.insert("end", "Modèle avec infection latente")
    v.insert("end", "Modèle avec traitement")
    v.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.OnDouble)
    v.grid(row=2,column=0)

    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)


def Double(self, event):

    widget = event.widget
    selection=widget.curselection()
    value = widget.get(selection[0])
    print(value)
    return(selection)
```

> This is where it doesn't work

```
lisi=Double(self, event)
if lisi==(0,):
    print(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = simpleapp_tk(None)
app.title('Projet informatique')
app.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any kind of help !

Comment: The user clicks on the listbox, that's what I meant with interaction. It's the "Double" function.

Comment: I will work on this question when I have time if still no one gives an answer. I like the question

Comment: Should your `Double` function be called `OnDouble` instead, in line with `v.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.OnDouble)`?

Comment: Also, what exactly is your expected output, and what is the output you are getting?  There's nothing in your code that indicates that you want another Tkinter widget to open.  Are you trying to print intermediate result, and getting something unexpected?

Comment: I am working on the seperate window right now. When I print the result in the double function it works fine but i can't seem to use the function to return a value that i could use to write an if.

Comment: It looks like you have an indentation problem.  The definition of `Double` and `initialize` Should be at the same level as `__init__`. Also, the last three lines have incorrect indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Functions that are bound to events shouldn't return anything, because there's no place to return the data to. There is no function waiting for the result. By the time the user clicks, the main logic of your program will have finished, and `mainloop` will be running.

The last part of your code example doesn't make any sense. You typically don't ever call a bound function directly. Instead, you wait for the user to invoke the event (ie: double-click the widget).

Answer (score -1):

Tkinter is not easy at first sight, but after some mistakes is really useful. I'm pretty sure you'll agree with me between some days ;)
I changed a little bit your script. I don't think you need to subclass Tkinter's class inside yours. As you can see i didn't. Maybe it's not exactly what you need, but it can be a good start point I guess. As you can note I changed grid layout with pack: if you play with it a bit it's more flexible than grid layout and can give a better user experince. Btw I used grid layout inside children window so you can look there if you have some trouble. 
I hope this can help you.

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root      = Tk()
        self.labelVariable = StringVar()
        self.root.title('Projet informatique')
        self.initialize()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def initialize(self):
        #You don't need to let your class be an instance of Tkinter class. 
        #Therefore you doesn't need self.grid() call.
        #Just create a main frame from "self.root" (Tk instance) and put widgets
        #inside the frame. You could also need to create several frame,
        #for more complex layouts, but this doesn't seems the case...
        #Main frame(used to contain widgets):
        self.main = Frame(self.root)
        #In this window i used "pack" manager just to show you a quicker way to 
        #accomplish your task, but it's just an example.
        self.main.pack() 

        label = Label(self.main, textvariable=self.labelVariable, font=('courier',10,'bold'), anchor="w", fg="red", bg="white")
        label.pack()

        self.labelVariable.set(u"Modélisation de populations atteintes d'un virus")

        v=Listbox(self.main)
        v.insert("end","Modèle SIR")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle de Witowski")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle de Munz")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle avec infection latente")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle avec traitement")
        v.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.Double) #your method call must match. In this case i drop "On" and it works.
        #v.grid(row=2,column=0) #your old code to layout widget
        v.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH) #another way to layout widgets

        #self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

    def Double(self,event):
        widget    = event.widget
        selection = widget.curselection()
        value     = widget.get(selection[0])
        self.newWindow(value)
        #Your function doesn't need to return anything (if i understood what you meant!)
        #return(selection)

    def ModifyTextarea(self,elem,msg,clear=None):
        """This function let you modify a text widget easier. It's just an helper function"""
        elem.config(state=NORMAL)
        if clear:
            elem.delete(1.0, END)
        else:
            elem.insert(END,msg)
        elem.config(state=DISABLED)

    def newWindow(self,msg):
        """This is the function you asked for. It creates a new window clicking on main window items. I layout it with grid layout as you can see"""
        top = Toplevel(self.root)
        q1 = Frame(top)
        q1.pack()
        top.grab_set()

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(q1)
        scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=NS)
        text = Text(q1,relief=FLAT,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,state=DISABLED,exportselection=True)
        text.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

        lbl = Label(q1,text="")
        lbl.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3)

        self.ModifyTextarea(text,msg)

        scrollbar.configure(command=text.yview)

        btnquit = Button(q1,borderwidth = 1,text = "Ok",command = lambda: top.destroy())
        btnquit.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W+E)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """I put all tkinter logic inside GUI class in this way you only need to instantiate it, but if you prefer, you can add an additional method "show", it's up to you. This is just an example"""
    app = GUI()
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you described the single thing that was causing the problem. Otherwise, the reader is forced to compare the code line by line looking for changes. Plus, they will have to figure out which of your changes are related to the problem, and which are just extra changes you decided to throw in (such as using pack instead of grid)

Comment: Bryan you're right, sorry. But mainly, as said, I changed the package layout instead of grid layout, avoided to use Tkinter's hierarchy because it's not needed and added from scratch the method to open new window as user request. Oh maybe i forgot to mention that i used "from tkinter import *" syntax so there is no need to prefix "tkinter." any Tkinter's widget...

Comment: I recommend saying that in your answer, and distinguish between things that  are your personal preferences versus the changes that actually solve the problem. Personally I disagree with changing the import statement -- PEP8 clearly says global imports are bad. Even though python's own tkinter documentation uses global import in its examples, as do several tutorials, it's not the right way to write code.

Comment: My answer would just be a snippet to help the user to create new windows on items click as he asked. Not a complete working application. I just join my code with his. I hope my answer edit could fit comunity request. Finally I'm sorry if my english is not good enough (i have some trouble as i'm not a native speaker) for this reason my comments are so short.